# How to consume text until newline in ANTLR?

Tags: antlr

How do you do something like this with ANTLR?

Example input:

```
title: hello world
```

Grammar:

```
header : IDENT ':' REST_OF_LINE ;
IDENT : 'a'..'z'+ ;
REST_OF_LINE : ~'\n'* '\n' ;
```

It fails, with `line 1:0 mismatched input 'title: hello world\n' expecting IDENT`

(I know ANTLR is overkill for parsing MIME-like headers, but this is just at the top of a more complex file.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It fails, with line 1:0 mismatched input 'title: hello world\n' expecting IDENT

You must understand that the lexer operates independently from the parser. No matter what the parser would "like" to match at a certain time, the lexer simply creates tokens following some strict rules:

1. try to match tokens from top to bottom in the lexer rules (rules defined first are tried first);
2. match as much text as possible. In case 2 rules match the same amount of text, the rule defined first will be matched.

Because of rule 2, your `REST_OF_LINE` will always "win" from the `IDENT` rule. The only time an `IDENT` token will be created is when there's no more `\n` at the end. That is what's going wrong with your grammars: the error messages states that it expects a `IDENT` token, which isn't found (but a `REST_OF_LINE` token is produced).

> I know ANTLR is overkill for parsing MIME-like headers, but this is just at the top of a more complex file.

You can't just define tokens (lexer rules) you want to apply to the header of a file. These tokens will also apply to the rest of the more complex file. Perhaps you should pre-process the header separately from the rest of the file?

Answer (score -1):

antlr parsing is usually done in 2 steps.
1. construct your ast
2. define your grammer

pseudo code (been a few years since I played with antlr) - AST:

```
WORD : 'a'..'z'+ ;
SEPARATOR : ':';
SPACE : ' ';
```

pseudo code - tree parser:

```
header: WORD SEPARATOR WORD (SPACE WORD)+
```

Hope that helps....

Comment: Unfortunately I want to read all the text to the end of the line, which might include numbers, letters, punctuation.

Comment: No, you don't start with an AST, you start with a grammar. Besides, producing an AST isn't even mandatory: you could just work with the parse tree.